# How to use 'target_sources' command with INTERFACE library?

Tags: c++, cmake

My project is organized in subdirectories (a dozen), there are some includes between subdirectories. Some of these subdirectories contains only header files (dir1 for example).

Here is a look at the organization of the project:

```
project
 |
 |----- src -- dir1  <-- header-only library
 |       |      |--- dir1.h
 |       |      |--- CMakeLists.txt
 |       |
 |       |
 |       | --- dir2
 |       |      |--- dir2.cpp
 |       |      |--- dir2.h
 |       |      |--- CMakeLists.txt
 |       |
 |       | --- file.h
 |       | --- CMakeLists.txt 
 |
 |
 |----- test -- dir1 -- test.cpp
 |       | ---- dir2 -- test.cpp
 |       | ---- includeFile.h
 |
 |
 |----- CMakeLists.txt
```

I want to have a library containing all the code from src directory and an executable to run unit tests. After some research on stackOverFlow and Cmake examples, I arrived to these CMake files. There is one makefile per src subdirectories, one for grouping all the library and one global.

dir1 CMakeLists

```
add_library(dir1 INTERFACE)
target_sources(dir1 INTERFACE dir1.h)
target_include_directories(dir1 INTERFACE
  "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/dir1"
)
```

dir2 CMakeLists

```
set(dir2_src
  dir2.cpp dir2.h
)

add_library(dir2 ${dir2_src})
```

src CMakeLists

```
add_subdirectory(dir1)
add_subdirectory(dir2)


add_library(TheProject INTERFACE)
target_sources(TheProject INTERFACE file.h)
target_include_directories(TheProject INTERFACE
  "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/"
)
target_link_libraries(TheProject INTERFACE dir1
                                dir2
                                ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
```

main CMakeLists.txt

```
project(TheProject)

# gtest
# boost
# compilation flags ...

####### include paths
include_directories("./src/")
include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})

####### library to compile
add_subdirectory(src)


####### executable
file(GLOB SRCS utest/*/*.cpp)
add_executable(utest ${SRCS} test/includeFile.h)

target_link_libraries(utest gtest_main TheProject)
```

I almost used the same organization on a smaller project without header only libraries and INTERFACE and it worked. Here, I have an error with the different interface libraries:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:88 (add_executable):
  Cannot find source file:

    file.h

  Tried extensions .c .C .c++ .cc .cpp .cxx .m .M .mm .h .hh .h++ .hm .hpp
  .hxx .in .txx
```

I think I have not well understood the use of INTERFACE. I have done some research but nothing solve my problem.

And I have also a few questions:

- There is some dependancies between directories, (e.g. code in dir1 has an include of some dir2 files), should I specify these dependance in their cmake file (with target_link_libraries(dir2 dir1)) ?
- In the code, include are specified with relative paths in src and utest, is it not better to use paths like "dir1/dir1.h"?

Comment: `is it not better to use paths like "dir1/dir1.h"?` - It is fully up to you. While different "public" files has *different names* (from `#include` directive), everything is OK. `There is some dependancies between directories ..., should I specify these dependance in their cmake file?` - Most likely, you needn't to care about these dependencies. There is no such thing in CMake like "dependencies between directories": CMake only tracks files. Also, if some header file will change, the executable which uses it will be rebuilt on next `make` invocation.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Before CMake 3.13 *relative* paths, passed to `target_sources`, are interpreted **relative to further invocations** of `add_executable` (or `add_library`).

Because you call `add_executable()` from the top directory, CMake searches `test.h` relative to the top directory, not relative to the `src/` one.

Use **absolute paths** for `target_sources` calls:

```
target_sources(TheProject INTERFACE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/file.h)
```

---

Since CMake 3.13 relative paths passed to `target_sources` are resolved immediately, relative to the **current** source directory. See [@markhc's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56050353/3440745).

Comment: This behavior was changed on CMake 3.13, see my answer below.

Answer (score 6):

As an addon to Tsyvarev answer to anyone that comes across this from google, the behavior for `target_sources` was changed on CMake 3.13.

You can now use relative paths in `target_sources` calls.

https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.13/command/target_sources.html

> Relative source file paths are interpreted as being relative to the current source directory